# writing custom codecs for android using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am doing a video compression project for Android and I am thinking of implementing it by designing a new video codec (by scratch , I have designed the algorithm) . I have already read the basics of video compression , related relevant algorithms and codec basics . I have also found that **FFmpeg** may serve as a quite good solution on Android.

Now my questions come:

1. How to **write** a **new** video codec as in FFmpeg? I am still a beginner at writing codecs , but 
   how do I start ? I have a rough idea that that you have to write at least a demuxer first and then the specific encoder and decoder etc . (Asking for references here please.)
2. Since my codec deosn't simply adjust video properties like fps , resolution , bit-rate etc.
   Is reading the **MediaCodec** API  and MediaPlayer API in official Android SDK enough for writing new codecs ? (Because last time I saw it had only support for MPEG-4 SP , H.263 and H.264 . I was unable to find if you could directly write your own classes and functions).

Thanks .

Comment: Isn't anyone out there ? Please help . The project deadline is closing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg as a tool or the ffmpeg set of libraries (libavcodec, libaviformat, …) on Android. You can add or change ffmpeg codecs in a cross- platform manner, because this project puts a strong emphasis on platform independence. You can use the MediaCodec API instead. <s>But there is no way to extend the MediaCodec API</s> (**update** it is possible to extend MediaCodec, it is documented at http://source.android.com/devices/media.html#codecs ) and no easy way to let ffmpeg use this API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I'm getting the most troubled at is I don't know how to PROGRAM codecs . Googling for ffmpeg documentation did give me some results , but they are not readable as a newcomer to multimedia programming . Any references on ffmpeg OR how to write a codec from scratch? Thanks again .

Comment: The architecture of ffmpeg is relatively well documented on the official site, but I would rather suggest that you take an existing codec as the basis and gradually change it to do whatever you intend.

Comment: yeah , thanks for the update . But I guess the link that you referred me to is indeed a HARDWARE-codec , needing modifications in the firmware and that's something which can't do at this moment (I am trying to write a SOFTWARE codec) . I had one idea though ... Is it possible to implement the codec by adding the codec to mplayer ?? There are links which enable adding custom codec to mplayer ... but I don't know how to do that ;( . Please help out . Thanks again .

Comment: The purpose of this framework is to provide access to hardware codecs, but definitely you can add a software-only codec to it, just the same way as you would add a hardware codec. Android comes from the Git tree with some software video codecs, and you can use them as examples. But anyway, extending MediaCodec API requires rebuilding or at least reconfiguring the whole device system.

Answer (score 2):

if you are a newb and "just want to do it in SW", than just do it in SW. I am assuming your algorithm does not need to be real-time, and compress video data on the fly, or you would need to use a HW codec.

This is from [Android MediaCodec Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)

```
 MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
 codec.configure(format, ...);
 codec.start();
 ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
 ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
 for (;;) {
   int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeoutUs);
   if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
     // fill inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex] with valid data
     ...
     codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, ...);
   }

   int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(timeoutUs);
   if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
     // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.
     ...
     codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, ...);
   } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
     outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
   } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
     // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
     MediaFormat format = codec.getOutputFormat();
     ...
   }
 }
 codec.stop();
 codec.release();
 codec = null;
```

On the line that reads "// outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered" apply your codec.

That is your first frame will be outputBuffers[0] to outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex]. Save off outputBufferIndex, i.e. outputBufferIndex_old = outputBufferIndex; then your next frame will be outputbuffers[outputBufferIndex_old] to outputbuffers[outputBufferIndex]. But this is a circular buffer, so in the for loop ... ahhhhh

something like this:

```
//init
int old = 0;
int len = codec.BufferInfo().size,buff_len=outputBuffers.size;
Byte[] processBuffer = new Byte[len];

... // outputBuffer ready
for (int i=old; i<old+len; i++){
   processBuffer[i-old] = outputBuffers[i%buff_len];
}
old = outputBufferIndex;
```

[Here](https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec) is a good example. You may want to look into MediaMetadataRetriever to get information about the input video. height and width ect. bytesize per pixel, if you want your encoder to be robust to different types of video. Anyway, that should get you started.

I strongly recommend Matlab(or GNU Octave) for prototyping a video codec. It will save you a ton of time. Meaning you should make sure your intended codec algorithm works before trying to implement it on a near impossible system to debug like Android.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles across this old question the answer is:

1. Write your Program.
2. Where you want the "Codec" to go simply add a 'null Codec' (copy Input to Output).
3. Test that your Program still works and that you can read the (so-called) encoded File.
4. Add your Codec where the 'null Codec' was (call a Function to avoid big edits to a working File).
5. Re-Test your Program to ensure it still works and read the Output to make sure it is correct.

That is all. ;)

Things to consider:

- A "Video Player" can drop Frames, a "Video Recorder" had better NOT
  drop Frames.
- A 'Software Codec' (no Hardware assist) will be slow,
  run it on a different Core, if available.
- A Hardware Codec (called from Software) will be necessary unless you are just making a 
  Demo.
- Split your Program into pieces that can run separately so it can be threaded and those Threads can be assigned to different Cores. You will need to detect the number of Cores and assess their speed so you can do some of the partitioning dynamically at Runtime.
- Use of the NDK and Assembly Language Programming will be necessary to get enough speed to compress a decent sized Video at a wanted frame rate (IE: you do not want your finished Program to only support 320x176 @ 5 FPS Videos). The Compressor MUST run faster than it's Input arrives.
- Designing your own Codec to beat an existing Codec (x265) will take you years (without help).
- If your a Wiz at Java, C, and ARM Assembly (and a Software Engineer) it will take more than a couple of months of work; so commit or quit. Try to find some Open Source as a base to start from.